# Given last node of singly linked list, how do we find head node

Tags: linked-list, singly-linked-list

Given last node of singly linked list, how do we find head node?

Let's say given JSON:

{
"id": "A",
"next": "B"
},
{
"id": "B",
"next": "C"
}
{
"id": "C",
"next": "D"
}
{
"id": "D",
"next": null
}

Now assume that above is not sorted and we need to figure out HEAD element 'A'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find an element that's `id` is not the value `next` of another object in the list. Assuming a valid non-empty singly-linked list there must be exactly one element which satisfies that condition (the head). If the list is empty `head` will be assigned the value `undefined`.

```js
const json = '[{"id": "A", "next": "B"}, {"id": "B", "next": "C"},{"id": "C", "next": "D"},{"id": "D", "next": null}]';
const objects = JSON.parse(json);

const head = objects.find( a => ! objects.find( b => a.id === b.next ) );

console.log( head );
```

Comment: Once I posted this post, even me too thought in the same lines where head node wouldn't be present in any of next attributes. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: @Paulpro How does the `!` work in this? Why doesn't it work using `objects.forEach(...);`? I couldn't find anything about it in the [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Comment: @DavidMichaelHuber It's just the [logical not operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT). If the inner `find` returns and object than the `!` will evaluate to `false`, otherwise it will evaluate to `true`.

Comment: @Paulpro For some reason this confuses me. Are you sure it really checks *the only element that's `id` is not the value `next` of another object in the list*? For me it looks like it checks the first element only for not having its `id` as `next` in any object of the list.

Comment: @DavidMichaelHuber You're right about that, which is why my answer starts with "Assuming a valid list". I should probably expand that to "Assuming a valid singly-linked list". There can only be one such element and there must be exactly one, so the first element satisfying the condition is the same as the only element satisfying the condition.

Comment: @DavidMichaelHuber I reworded my answer.

Comment: @Paulpro Thank you so much for clearing this up! It really confused me that my understanding of your explanation didn't match with my understanding of the code you provided.

Comment: No problem @DavidMichaelHuber . Sorry about the initial confusion.